# Sudoer does not use the same environnement for python3

Tags: linux, python-import, python-3.7, sudo, sudoers

I have a python script1 which i use as a library which i import to my main script.
before using it i checked that it was working fine, i noticed that when i run this script1 with "sudo" then it doesn't find one of library he use.

```
sudo python3 -W ignore detector.py -d datasets -c MLP predict
```

[image]

By searching a little, I found that "sudo" did not use the same environment as my user account, and that it was necessary to add the argument "-E", and it works well.

```
sudo -E python3 -W ignore detector.py -d datasets -c MLP predict
```

the script1 also  works  well when I run it without "sudo"

```
python3 -W ignore detector.py -d datasets -c MLP predict
```

Then i import my script1 into my main script "import script1" and call one of the functions from script1 but get the same error from script1.

the problem is that my main script is managed by systemctl with service with root user and i can't use "-E" in  ExecStart:

```
[Unit]

Description= Uplink manager with IA supervison of LORAWAN data
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target  
[Service]
ExecStart=  /usr/bin/python3 -u/opt/flask_server/uplink_server/uplink_manager.py
Restart=on-failure   
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=uplink_manager.service
```

Can you help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The library that was missing, was in fact present in the root environment, but the version of the library was not right.